# Constructing triangles using sides of tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve the following:

> Using six sides of tetrahedron, construct two triangles.

**My try:**

Let $SACB$ be a tetrahedron and denote sides as shown in image. Assume that $SC$ is longest side of the tetrahedron, i.e if we denote $SC=d$, then $d\ge w,x,y,z$.

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

Using the triangle inequality we have \begin{align*}x+y&\ge d\tag{1} \\ z+w&\ge d \tag{2}\end{align*}
Sum $(1)$ and $(2)$ - $\displaystyle \frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{z+w}{2}\ge d$.

It is easy for me to show that $\displaystyle d+\frac{z+w}{2}\ge \frac{x+y}{2}$ and $\displaystyle d+\frac{x+y}{2}\ge \frac{z+w}{2}$, hence we can construct a triangle with sides $\displaystyle d,\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{z+w}{2}$.

Now, denote $AB=\ell$. As it seems to me I need to show that we can construct another triangle with sides $\ell$ and some combination of $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2},\frac{z}{2},\frac{w}{2}$. I couldn't manage to show it.

Any hint or a feedback will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you're allowed to cut the edges into parts, then just cut each one into sixths and paste the bits together appropriately to create two identical equilateral triangles with edge-length $(w+x+y+z+d+\ell)/6$. That seems to easy. My reading of the instruction is that you need to show that there's always a way to take the six edges ---as unaltered wholes--- and arrange them as the edges of two triangles.

Comment: @Blue, and how can the latter be shown?

Comment: Well, that's the challenge, now isn't it? :)  I'm looking at it, but haven't found a solution ... yet.

Answer (score 1):

A notational preamble ...

We know that triangle with (non-negative) edge-lengths $x$, $y$, $z$ exists if and only if the tripartite Triangle Inequality holds:
$$x \leq y + z \qquad y \leq z + x \qquad z \leq x + y $$
One can show that the condition is equivalent to
$$\operatorname{heron}(x, y, z) \geq 0$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{heron}(x,y,z) &:= (x+y+z)(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z) \\
&\,= -x^4 - y^4 - z^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + 2 y^2 z^2 + 2 z^2 x^2 
\end{align}$$

Note that the heron is *strictly positive* for a non-degenerate triangle, but I choose to be inclusive.

(The product is called the "heron" because it's the heart of Heron's Formula for the area of the corresponding triangle (if it exists): $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\operatorname{heron}(x,y,z)}$, which highlights the necessity (though not the sufficiency) for the product to be non-negative. The $(x+y+z)$ factor isn't strictly necessary for testing triangle viability, but it streamlines the expanded form, which helps with an implicit calculation below.)

---

Now to the problem at hand ...

**If** we could say that, **for every vertex** of a tetrahedron, the edges meeting that vertex form a triangle, we'd be done: use the edges about any vertex to form one triangle, and use the edges about the opposite face to form the second triangle (which they clearly already do!). Unfortunately, **we *can't* say that**. (There are lots of tetrahedra such that the edges meeting at a vertex are, say, $1$, $1$, $1000$. No triangle there.) However, we *can* say that, **for at least one vertex** of any given tetrahedron, the edges meeting that vertex form a triangle. Here's why ...

Let our tetrahedron have edges $a$, $b$, $c$ about a vertex, with respective opposite edges $d$, $e$, $f$. One readily verifies that

> The sum of "face herons'' equals the sum of "vertex herons".

which is to say
$$\begin{align}
&\quad\; \operatorname{heron}(d,e,f) + \operatorname{heron}(d,b,c) + \operatorname{heron}(a,e,c) + \operatorname{heron}(a,b,f) \\
&= \operatorname{heron}(a,b,c) + \operatorname{heron}(a,e,f) +
\operatorname{heron}(d,b,f) + \operatorname{heron}(d,e,c)
\end{align} \tag{$\star$}$$

(You don't even have to multiply everything out yourself. Consulting the expanded formula given above, it's obvious that both sides of $(\star)$ contain two copies of the negative of the fourth power of each length; only-slightly-less-obviously, the various cross terms match: for instance, $a^2$ gets paired with $b^2$, $c^2$, $e^2$, $f^2$ on each side.)

Since "face herons" —calculated with edge-lengths from legitimate triangles— are individually non-negative, so is their sum; relation $(\star)$ then implies that **at least one** "vertex heron" must be non-negative: the edges meeting at the corresponding vertex must form a triangle. (More-specifically: if the faces are *non-degenerate* triangles, the edges at some vertex must form a *non-degenerate* triangle.) $\square$

---

We have shown that it's *always possible* to partition a tetrahedron's edges to form two triangles. If the task is to provide an *explicit* partition, then there's more work to do. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.